# Have slug populate from title or create random - Django Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I would like the slug to be generated automatically from the title the user imports, or have random integers generated if the title is blank. The way I currently have it, the slug is supposed to be populated from the form title, but I get an error saying the form doesn't have a title field.

So, I need to:

1. change the slug in the views.py to be populated from the inputed title
2. create a random integer generator if the title is blank (I'm assuming in models.py and views.py?)

Could someone please help me with this?

Thank you in advance! I appreciate any and all help!

***forms.py:***

```
class PhotoUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Title of photo", "size": "30"})
    )
    description = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"placeholder": "Description of photo"})
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('category', 'title', 'description', 'image')
```

***models.py:***

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, null=False, blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/photos/', null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, blank=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.creator)
```

***views.py:***

```
def photo_upload_view(request, username):
    u = MyUser.objects.get(username=username)
    form = PhotoUploadForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PhotoUploadForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES)
        new_slug = Photo.objects.get(slug=form.title)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.creator = request.user
            obj.slug = slugify(new_slug)
            obj.save()
            messages.success(request, "Thank you! You have successfully posted your picture!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        else:
            form = PhotoUploadForm()

    submit_btn = "Upload Post"

    context = {
        "submit_btn": submit_btn,
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "photos/photo_upload.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
new_slug = Photo.objects.get(slug=form.title)
```

You're setting the value of `new_slug` to a retrieved object, not a string. That isn't going to slugify. You probably just want this:

```
new_slug = form.title
```

But if you actually want to retrieve a value from a Photo, reference that attribute at the end, so:

```
new_slug = Photo.objects.get(slug=form.title).slug
```

As for generating a random integer:

```
from random import randint
randint(0,100)
```

Will return a random integer between 0 and 100 (inclusive).